# Using Cacheable annotation with treecache in Infinispan

Tags: spring-boot, caching, infinispan

I am attempting to use a TreeCache Infinispan implementation and I want to see if it will work with Spring Cacheable annotations.  I have a working example with key/value storage, but I can't find examples on how to do this with a tree storage mechanism.

I saw this post, but I can't find any documentation on this aspectj annotation:

[Wrong working infinispan tree cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724342/wrong-working-infinispan-tree-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Infinispan tree cache is no longer supported and has now been removed. Infinispan was created as a spin-off of JBoss Cache, that used a tree structure for keeping things in memory. We temporarily supported tree cache in Infinispan as a way to easily migrate users from JBoss Cache to Infinispan.

These days, if you want a tree structure, either you maintain it or you use [Hibernate OGM](https://hibernate.org/ogm/) which takes care of maintaining a complex object data structure inside Infinispan.